# Prove that $1-2(1-y)(1-x)\geq0$ when $x\in[0.5,1)$ and $y\in[0,0.5)$?

Tags: inequality

I am looking for the proof that $f(x,y)=1-2(1-y)(1-x)\geq0$ when $x\in[0.5,1)$ and $y\in[0,0.5)$. This seems to be true when plotted out.

Using the second partial derivative test does not seem to work as the critical points do not land within the restricted boundaries.

Is there a simple and elegant way to show this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce the inequality to $1/2\geq(1-x)(1-y)$ and then the bounds for $x$ and $y$ make the result immediate.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x>0$ you can reduce this to showing $1-2(1-y)(1-x) \ge 0$.

It is immediate that $(1-y)(1-x) \le 1 \cdot {1 \over 2}$, so
$1-2(1-y)(1-x) \ge 1-2 \cdot 1 \cdot {1 \over 2} \ge 0$.